# SSL installation on both GoDaddy and External server

Tags: ssl, iis, web-hosting

We have a wildcard ssl for *.domain.com purchased from GoDaddy. domain.com is a managed wordpress website hosted in GoDaddy.
We also have couple of servers where other websites are hosted as subdomains, api-client1.domain.com, api-client2.domain.com

Currently only subdomains are loading without any errors on https. The main domain is throwing a warning that SSL is expired, though its not.

In order to make sure that the domain and subdomain all load on https, is the below sequence of steps correct?

1) Ask GoDaddy to rectify the problem mentioning that https is not working.
2) After 1 is resolved, Create a CSR from external server, download the certificate from GoDaddy and install it in the external server.

Will the certificate installed by 1 revoked after 2 is done?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Check if you bind the wrong certificate in HTTP API.

Comment: The bindings are correct on our servers. No problems there.